# how can i protect my data in python-requests like, headers or data='username' from reverse engineering with burp suite

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, ssl-certificate

how can i protect my data in python-requests like, headers or `data="username"`  from reverse engineering with burp suite

```
import requests

hd = ('Host": "www.google.com")
requests.get("https://www.google.com",headers=hd,verify=true)
```

can someone Get cert file of python and reverse engineering with burp suite script requests output/inputs or that not easy ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The code you showed is client code,
which accesses a web site that you don't administer.

Burp suite is not relevant for that,
as it is intended to demonstrate weaknesses in a server's code or config.

The client side openssl certificates config controls
whether the client is willing to continue an https conversation
after obtaining a server cert chain that ends
with e.g. komodo, verisign, or self-signed.

If you wish to "protect" your data from the web server,
then don't send it, don't include it in the `headers`.

Comment: the python was have cert file Default in some dir /etc/ or /bin i dont remember if i give someone my code was complied with cython3 he can get Default cert and run it with burp suite to see ssl traffic not encyrpted  of my data requests  like cookies etc .. or he cant ?